# Why does not regression line from linear mixed effects model pass through means for each repeated measure?

Tags: mixed-model

In my dataset, there are 4 repeated measures (4 runs) from 24 subjects. So I applied linear mixed effects model with random effects = subjects. On the other hand, I figured out that the regression line doesn't pass through the averages of each run, I mean not even close. To me, it doesn't make sense. (The error bars shows 1 SE of X and Y)

[image]

At first, I thought it happened because my sample might not follow the normal distribution. So I generated 100 subjects x 4 runs with `np.random.normal`. Still, the lme regression line doesn't go through the means of each run.

[image]

It is super weird, because in my understanding, lme finds slope from 4 repeated measures, and finds the best fit from the 100 slopes. And since the slope is from 4 repeated measure of each subject, it should follow the mean of each repeated measure. What's wrong with my understanding?

If you don't understand my point, just ignore it and could you please explain why lme line does not pass through the means?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This thread about shrinkage in mixed models may be relevant: [Estimates of random effects in binomial model (lme4)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142810/237901).

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the line ought to go through all the means. In your first graph, a straight line that did that would come nowhere near the data.